# Removing mobogenie

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, malware

I saw the Mobogenie in my installed apps list. Uninstalled and it is coming back from somewhere when I connect to internet. I think this is a genuine app, but a bit concerned about the intrusive nature. Also it is posting notifications once it comes back. Does anyone had similar experience?  Is there a way to remove Mobogenie permanently?

Answer (score 1):

Mobogenie has been updated so users can decide either if they want to install our software or not. This solves the issue of consider Mobogenie as a spam software and focus in our content. Glad to have a further discussion to solve any remaining doubt.

Comment: Thanks for the details, Santiago! But could you please [edit] your post and include why the app re-installs itself when the user explicitly uninstalled it (as the OP reports) – and better yet, how to avoid that?

Comment: So you work for/at/with developers of mobogenie? Force installations, great.

Comment: even if that is an "option" it still is underhanded and sneaky. Mobogenie isnt the only one that practices "strange and weird" marketing practices. Forced downloads aren't done by choice, but the installation is? No good.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have uninstalled mobo genine market.
2. Go to App, and swipe until you see "All" you will see 2 Downloads icon there.
3. The Downloads with no size is the legit one. Keep it, if you long press and select App info you will see that it's something related to your firmware.
4. The 2nd Downloads icon is the culprit, with a version of 2.02xx. Long press it, select App info then uninstall.

Comment: When I go to apps list, I can see 2 Icons. One with name **Mobogenie**, other with name **Mobomarket**. I tried removing both. But unfortunately this comes back when I connect to internet again.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to safe mode. Safe mode can be activated by pressing and holding volume down button during boot up process. And then you can easily uninstall the app

Comment: That will put certain devices in download mode. You should specify what other ways there are to accomplish this. As the answer stands it should be a comment.